# Cannot transfer a large 30 GB SQL table from a client SQL Server machine to my Azure Data Lake Gen2 as a 530 MB Parquet File

Tags: sql-server-2008, bigdata, parquet, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I cannot copy a 30 GB SQL Server table from this machine to my Azure Data Lake Gen 2 storage account as a 530 MB Parquet file using Azure Data Factory. The compression type is gzip. The Throughput is 11.8 MB/s

The copy detail:
[image]

The failed ADF copy error message is:

```
{ "errorCode": "2200", "message": "Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedBlobFSOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=BlobFS operation failed for: A task was canceled.. Account: &apos;datalake&apos;. FileSystem: &aposcontainer-dl&apos;. Path: &apos;ImportLayer/F61ILBarAcct_Txns.parquet&apos;.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException,Message=A task was canceled.,Source=mscorlib,'", "failureType": "UserError", "target": "Copy Latest Source Data" }
```

It is the same on the client integration runtime log

```
DEBUG:
TraceComponentId: TransferClientLibrary
TraceMessageId: BlobFSOperationRetry
@logId: Warning
jobId: c063e070-cc12-4cae-895f-f8ada2bfa3ff
activityId: ecfa652d-8471-4297-be2a-4ecc0ebc89c5
eventId: BlobFSOperationRetry
message: 'Type=System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException,Message=A task was canceled.,Source=mscorlib,StackTrace=   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.AzureDfsClient.&lt;UpdatePathWithHttpMessagesAsync&gt;d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.AzureDfsClientExtensions.&lt;UpdatePathAsync&gt;d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.AzureDfsClientExtensions.UpdatePath(IAzureDfsClient operations&#44; String action&#44; String filesystem&#44; String path&#44; Nullable`1 position&#44; Nullable`1 retainUncommittedData&#44; String contentLength&#44; String xMsLeaseAction&#44; String xMsLeaseId&#44; String xMsCacheControl&#44; String xMsContentType&#44; String xMsContentDisposition&#44; String xMsContentEncoding&#44; String xMsContentLanguage&#44; String xMsProperties&#44; String ifMatch&#44; String ifNoneMatch&#44; String ifModifiedSince&#44; String ifUnmodifiedSince&#44; Stream requestBody&#44; String xMsClientRequestId&#44; Nullable`1 timeout&#44; String xMsDate)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.BlobFSClient.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass37_0.&lt;AppendFile&gt;b__1()
   at Microsoft.Rest.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass16_0.&lt;ExecuteAction&gt;b__0()
   at Microsoft.Rest.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func),'
```

On the client machine, the cpu is a Intel Xeon E7-2830 @2.13Ghz, 64bit OS. It has 16.0 GB of Ram. It has a 40 GB Hard drive with 10 GB free space. I increase the virtual memory max to 10 GB so it can use the free space. For the Java pption, I set -Xmx, Java max heap memory, to 26 GB to take advantage of that. I can only use this client machine which has the Integration Runtime installed on it.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage  to solve it by using the compression type snappy instead of gzip. It uses less processing power.

In addition, i ran the copy one at a time instead of many at once. It is slower but safer

Comment: Hello.
Can you please explain what do you mean by "i ran the copy one at a time instead of many at once."?
Do you have one activity per pipeline? Or set `

> Degree of copy parallelism

` to 1 instead of default "Auto"?

Comment: No, I copy data via a ForEach activity. It execute a copy activity over a collection of tables.  I set the 'Sequential' setting to on so it does a copy one at a time or sequentially. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity

Comment: does it mean that only one activity is active?
I have suspicion that multiple active activities are the cause of the problem.
Though it doesn't expalain why it brakes after abt 1 hour...

Comment: Yes, that is what sequential means. Please read the article as well.

it all depends on how big the tables you are copying. If the copies are small, you can run multiple of them at the same time. If they are really big like in my case, using snappy and running them sequentially helps. I don't know exactly why it breaks, but it seems compressing large table with gzip to parquet file type is more process heavy than gzip. Please look up gzip vs snappy.

Comment: well, "very big" in big data world is definitely more than 7.5GB of data -))
Anyway, today opened ticket with Microsoft.. They escalated it to dev team. Will let you know what is outcome.